# Plotting uniform and Gaussian random variables

Tags: matlab, gaussian, random

I want to create uniform and Gaussian (normal) random variables in MATLAB via `rand` and `randn` syntax. And I would like to plot the PDF and CDF of aforementioned random variables with two methods. 
The first one, *determining Relative Frequency*, the second one, *Histogram*.

Also, how can I prove that `rand` syntax corresponds to Uniform RV and `randn` syntax corresponds to Normal RV?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  What is your question?  Can you read the manual entries on [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html?searchHighlight=rand) and [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html?searchHighlight=randn) ? Is that proof enough?  In any event, your question seems either about programming in Matlab, or asking us to write a program for you.  Please rephrase your question to ask about this you don't understand, rather than asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction!!!   How can i plot CDF of a Uniform and Gaussian RVs in MATLAB?

Comment: For plotting PDF, i use below MATLAB code. Is it true or not?                                                                                                                   numsamples = 1e+6;  /    hist(rand(1,numsamples))

Comment: YEAH, if you can just proof it,,,, how can i proof it??????

Answer (score 0):

cumsum command of MATLAB can be used to plot CDF while as histogram command can be used to plot PDF of RVs. Check out the following links for detailed description:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html?refresh=true

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html

Comment: What about "cdfplot" synatx that draws emricial CDF of a arbitrary RV?

Comment: Cdfplot requires statistics toolbox. Without the toolbox you can use cumsum function.